# Collapse character vector into single string with each string on its own row

Tags: r, vector, text, paste

How do you collapse a character vector with multiple strings into a single string and with spacing between each string so that each string will start on a new line/row in the collapsed string?

I have a multiple string character vector like this:

```
text <- c("This should be first row", "This should be second row", "This should be third row")
```

I would like to collapse it into a single string, but create spacing so that each string have an individual row. Essentially, I want the string to look like the output from cat(paste()).

```
cat(paste(text, collapse = "\n"))
```

However, if try to store the output from cat(paste(text, collapse = "\n")), the object returns as NULL.

```
test <- cat(paste(text, collapse = "\n"))
```

Any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: the value of `paste(text, collapse = '\n')` is what you are looking for. NOte that the `cat` prints the value on the screen. The printing is for human eyes. Not for the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to create an object that stores data in the way that you want except when you parse the `\n` characters. Whitespace in strings are meaningful, i.e. spaces will be preserved when a string is printed. However,  how those whitespaces appear in your console will vary for a number of reasons. As it is now, your string already has the characters to tell other functions that will process it to print each substring on its own line.

```r
text <- c("This should be first row",
          "This should be second row",
          "This should be third row")

# This is what you did
# Notice that you can't assign to an object and it prints to console!
test <- cat(paste(text, collapse = "\n"))
#> This should be first row
#> This should be second row
#> This should be third row

print(test)
#> NULL

# This is what you want: sending the object itself
test2 <- paste(text, collapse = "\n")

print(test2)
#> [1] "This should be first row\nThis should be second row\nThis should be third row"
```